# Is measurable function always well-defined?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

Suppose that $G=$`{A_1,...,A_n}` is a partition of $\Omega$ and let $F$ be the sigma-algebra generated by $G$. My task is to prove that if a function $X$ is a random variable, then it is constant over each set $A_i$. Here's my work:

First, let $X$ be a random variable from $\Omega$ to $R$. Then for a generic Borel set $H$ in $R$, we have that $X^{-1}(H)$ belongs to $F$. Next, suppose for contradiction that $X$ is not constant over each set $A_i$, so that in some $A_i$, there exist elements $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ such that $X(\omega_1)\ne X(\omega_2)$.

Because $X(\omega_1)$ and $X(\omega_2)$ are technically Borel sets in $R$ and $X$ is a random variable, we then know that $X^{-1}X(\omega_1)=\omega_1\in F$ and $X^{-1}X(\omega_2)=\omega_2\in F$.

Since $G$ is a partition and $\omega_1,\omega_2\in A_i$, we kow that $\omega_1,\omega_2$ do not belong to $A_j$ for $j\ne i.$ Furthermore, because $\omega_1,\omega_2\in A_i$ and $\omega_1,\omega_2\in F$, it must be that $\omega_1=\omega_2=A_i$.

But if $\omega_1=\omega_2$, then $X(\omega_1)=X(\omega_2)$, a contradiction. Hence, $X$ is constant over each element of the partition.

---

The last line of my proof depends on the fact that $X$ is well-defined, and so I'm left wondering if this is necessarily true given that $X$ is a random variable. It seems to be true intuitively, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Out of many things, probably the first thing I should point out is that $X^{-1}X(\omega) \neq \omega$. First of all, it is a _set_. But even then, $X^{-1}X(\omega) \neq \{\omega\}$. It's just that $\omega \in X^{-1}X(\omega)$.

Comment: It is not always the case that $X^{-1}X(\omega_1) = \omega_1$. This is a flaw in your proof but one that can be easily remedied.

Comment: *Hint for a proof:* You got to prove that if $A_i \supseteq A \in F$, then $A = \varnothing$.

Comment: Also, I notice the sentence “Furthermore, because $\omega_1,\omega_2 \in A_i$...it must be that $\omega_1=\omega_2=A_i$” does not appear to make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote $G = \{A_1, \dots, A_n\}$ the finite partition of $\Omega$ and let $\mathcal{G} = \sigma(G)$. The first observation about $\mathcal{G}$ is that it is a finite collection. The second observation about $\mathcal{G}$ is that every $E \in \mathcal{G}$ can be expressed as a finite union of the $A_i$.

Suppose $X : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable. Suppose $\omega_1, \omega_2 \in \Omega$ are chosen such that $X(\omega_1) \ne X(\omega_2)$. Of course, 
$$X^{-1}[X(\omega_1)] \cap X^{-1}[X(\omega_2)] = \emptyset.$$ 
The sets $\{X(\omega_1)\}$ and $\{X(\omega_2)\}$ being $\mathbb{R}$-measurable, it follows that both $X^{-1}[X(\omega_1)], X^{-1}[X(\omega_2)] \in \mathcal{G}$. By the second observation, we can write $X^{-1}[X(\omega_1)]$ and $X^{-1}[X(\omega_2)]$ as finite unions of the $A_i$. But since $X^{-1}[X(\omega_1)]$ and $X^{-1}[X(\omega_2)]$ are disjoint, it follows that each $A_i$ is included in at most one of the two unions. It follows that $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ do not belong to the same partition element $A_i$. Therefore, $X$ is constant on the elements of $G$.

Comment: Could you explain the "Of course,.." part of the second paragraph? How do we know that the intersection of the pre-images would be empty?

Comment: Suppose $\xi \in X^{-1}[X(\omega_1)]$. Then $X(\xi) = X(\omega_1) \ne X(\omega_2)$. Therefore, $\xi \notin X^{-1}[X(\omega_2)]$. And the reverse direction.